# Which will be the better option Apache or IIS?

Tags: web-server

I have to report to my manager regarding the new web server , but I am unable to decide to go with Apache or IIS. And shall we host the web server in our company or shall we let the ISP take care of that?

Our company deals with Real Estate and with workforce of over 500 . And we have .Net / ASP
application running on intranet. All the clients/users have Microsoft Windows Xp installed.
SQL 2000 as database server on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: throw us a bone dude, what's it going to be doing? what's the app running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my view it all depends on what you are planning to host on your new web server,

Static files / static html then go Apache as its generally cheaper.

If its php / java / ruby then again Apache.

.Net / ASP Classic then IIS

I would always host your web server in a dedicated data centre as the chance of a single point failure is far less then if you have it within your company ans also it means you dont have to worry about bandwidth and the physical connection.

Answer (score 0):

Other things to keep in mind when deciding:

- What expertise do you have in the company?
- Are you going to contract out content creation to an outside firm and what would they prefer?
- Is this web server for internal use only or is it going to be feeding out content to the internet writ large?
- Are you staffed to maintain a webserver or should you use a shared-services firm?
- If you are a Microsoft Office shop that is highly document focused then you may want to use a IIS/Sharepoint stack.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors that would heavily influence my decision:

- what operating system will you use, and
- what your company's predominant skill base is

Running Apache on Win32 isn't as straightforward as on Linux/Unix.

IIS installs and configurations are difficult to automate, whereas this can be done easily for Apache.

If people in your company are predominantly Microsoft users and have no experience with Linux then it is usually best to stick with Microsoft products.

If you have Unix/Linux people I would favour Apache in such an environment.